# CodeIgniter Datatable joined search (json_encoded data)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I have a serverside datatable which is taking some results from a table called `leads`.

In this leads table I have a column called `permission` that is json_encoded;

example: `{"13":["view"]}`

The number, '13', is associated with an user_id from my `accounts` table.

The search is working on all the other fields that are strings so I decided to make some sort of JOIN statement so I can read that field as a string as well.

I got stuck when I realized that I can't really process that JSON data as a simple ID to make the JOIN statement.
Therefore, something like:

```
 if (!empty($this->db->field_exists('permission', $this->table))) {

     $this->db->join("accounts AS t2", "t2.user_id = leads.permission"); 

 }
```

wouldn't work because `t2.user_id` would be a number indeed but `leads.permission` would be the json encoded string

If you need any more info I'll be happy to edit my post.

Thank you!

Ambiguous error

```
 SELECT `tbl_leads`.`email` as `email`, `tbl_leads`.`contact_name` as `contact_name`, `tbl_leads`.`phone` as `phone`, `tbl_leads`.`lead_status_id` as `lead_status_id`, `tbl_leads`.`permission` as `permission`, `tbl_leads`.`linkedin` as `linkedin`, `tbl_leads`.`leads_id` as `leads_id`, `tbl_leads`.`converted_client_id` as `converted_client_id`, `t2`.`username` as `namexx`
FROM `tbl_leads`
JOIN `tbl_users` AS `t2` ON `t2`.`user_id` = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(tbl_leads.permission), '$[0]'))
WHERE   (
`lead_name` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `contact_name` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `email` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `phone` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `lead_status_id` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `permission` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `namexx` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `linkedin` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `leads_id` LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'
 )
AND `converted_client_id` = '0'
ORDER BY `leads_id` DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

This is created by

```
   if ($this->table == 'tbl_leads') {

        //  $this->db->join("tbl_users AS t2", "t2.user_id = tbl_leads.permission"); 


         $this->db->select ( 
          'tbl_leads.email as email,
          tbl_leads.contact_name as contact_name,
          tbl_leads.phone as phone,
          tbl_leads.lead_status_id as lead_status_id,
          tbl_leads.permission as permission,
          tbl_leads.linkedin as linkedin,
          tbl_leads.leads_id as leads_id,
          tbl_leads.converted_client_id as converted_client_id,
          t2.username as namexx'); 

          $this->db->join("tbl_users AS t2", "t2.user_id = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(tbl_leads.permission), '$[0]'))"); 



        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the use of [MySQL JSON search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) :

```
if (!empty($this->db->field_exists('permission', $this->table))) {

    $this->db->join("accounts AS t2", "t2.user_id = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(leads.permission), '$[0]'))"); 

}
```

Firstly `JSON_KEYS` will return the json key as an array formatted string, then the `JSON_EXTRACT` will extract it as string, and finally the `JSON_UNQUOTE` will remove the quotes.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Any idea how to do the join so the two fields don't overwrite? Right now when i do this, my e-mail field from 'leads' is overwritten by the email field in accounts.

Comment: You could simply use alias on the `select` query, like `$this->db->select('t2.*,  leads.*, t2.email account_email, leads.email leads_email', false);`?

Comment: The problem is that when i search something, I'm getting an ambiguous column name error in the WHERE, even if I created an alias like: leads_email as email.

Comment: you can check my edited question. The IF is the single thing I want to modify so I don't have to edit the whole search function only for this.

Comment: so this `tbl_users` table also have an `email` field, correct? maybe that's what causing the ambiguous error message?

Comment: both tbl_users and tbl_leads have an email field. thats what I only selected the email field from tbl_users and aliased it as email. but its not recognized in the where query

Comment: what if you change `OR  email LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'` to `OR  tbl_leads.email LIKE '%w%' ESCAPE '!'`?

Comment: I have no idea where the SEARCH function is implemented so I can do some IFs and implement the table name in the ->where()

Comment: Lets say I found where the search function is implemented and I also did the tbl_leads.email. The problem is now I'm getting unkown column for namexx in the WHERE clause

Comment: This makes me confused since you don't mention the whole picture of your query. Where's the `where()` code? Is it still relevant with the main question?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737364/php-mysql-unkown-column-in-where-join