# PHP - MYSQL Unkown Column in WHERE Join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a generated query using CodeIgniter and datatables.

The query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT `tbl_leads`.*, t2`.`username` as `namexx`
FROM `tbl_leads`
JOIN `tbl_users` AS `t2` ON `t2`.`user_id` = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(tbl_leads.permission), '$[0]'))
WHERE   (
`tbl_leads`.`lead_name` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `tbl_leads`.`contact_name` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `tbl_leads`.`email` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `tbl_leads`.`phone` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `tbl_leads`.`lead_status_id` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `tbl_leads`.`permission` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `t2`.`username` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `tbl_leads`.`linkedin` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `tbl_leads`.`leads_id` LIKE '%d%' ESCAPE '!'
 )
AND `converted_client_id` = '0'
ORDER BY `leads_id` DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

This query gets generated on a POST request for search.

If you haven't already guessed, I'm getting

> Unknown column 't2.username' in 'where clause`

because the column alias isn't recognized in the where query(neither does `tbl_users.username` if it would be to change it).

I'm generating it through the next(datatables model):

```php
    if ($this->table == 'tbl_leads') {    
      $this->db->select ('tbl_leads.*, t2.username as namexx'); 
      $this->db->join("tbl_users AS t2", "t2.user_id = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(tbl_leads.permission), '$[0]'))", "LEFT"); 
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

I also edited the search function so i get the table pointers as follows(I know its not a good practice and redundant):

```
        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column

    {

        if ($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search

        {

            if ($i === 0) // first loop

            {

                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    if($this->table=='tbl_leads'){
                    if( $item=='namexx'){
                    $this->db->like('tbl_users.username', $_POST['search']['value']);
                        }else{
                        $this->db->like($this->table.'.'.$item, $_POST['search']['value']);

                        }
                    }else{
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);

                }

            } else {
                if($this->table=='tbl_leads'){
                if( $item=='namexx'){
                $this->db->or_like('tbl_users.username', $_POST['search']['value']);

                }else{
                $this->db->or_like($this->table.'.'.$item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                }else{
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);

                }

            }

            if (count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop

                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket

        }

        $i++;

    }
```

Comment: missing grave accent  in first row `SELECT tbl_leads.*, t2.username as namexx`

Comment: Note that `'%d...'` cannot use an index, which renders this kind of thing horribly inefficent - but sometimes there's not much you can do about that

Comment: *"but sometimes there's not much you can do about that"* @Strawberry what about  a `FULL TEXT` index with a `MATCH()` in boolean mode?

Comment: .. also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query, remove the `t2` alias from the join statements like this :

```
if ($this->table == 'tbl_leads') {
    $this->db->select ('tbl_leads.*, tbl_users.username as namexx');
    $this->db->join("tbl_users", "tbl_users.user_id = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(tbl_leads.permission), '$[0]'))", "LEFT");
}
$query = $this->db->get();
```